# Wire.read return signed or unsigned value

Tags: c, types, return, arduino, i2c

I am writing for Arduino and I use the [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) protocol. When `Wire.read()` returns an int, what is this int? Is it signed or unsigned?

At the Arduino official site it says that it returns a byte. So I think it is unsigned because they do not say sbyte or signed byte. If the register I read with `Wire.read()` has values (signed) that are saved with the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) method, how can `Wire.read()` understand it?

Is the return value always signed? Or does it depend?

Also, by reading and printing the value I get negative numbers, so that means that `wire.read()` returns an signed int.

Comment: `byte` is unsigned by definition: its value is 0-255.

Comment: thank you i mensioned that but the register value i read gives me negative number with Serial.print(_the_value_)

Comment: `read()` returns signed value if it success it returns number of bytes, if it fails for any reason it returns -1

Comment: Wire

read()
Description

Reads a byte that was transmitted from a slave device to a master after a call to requestFrom() or was transmitted from a master to a slave. read() inherits from the Stream utility class.

Syntax

Wire.read()
Parameters

none
this is from original site.
Returns

The next byte received

Comment: this is from the original site. but ok the answer you give explains why i get negative numbers but how can i be sure?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the return always signed?

Technically, yes. Wire.read() returns a signed int. However, the actual value should 0-255 (like an unsigned byte) or, as Grijesh says, if the read fails it returns a -1.

> If the register I read with Wire.read() has values (signed) that are saved with the two's complement method, how can Wire.read() understand it?

My understanding is that the I²C protocol sends 8-bit bytes. It doesn't have any concept of signed or unsigned. If the device you are communicating with sends two's complement signed values, it may be as simple as casting the results of the read to a `char` type.

For example,

```
int r;
char c;
r = Wire.read();
if (r != -1) {
    c = char(r);
}
```

Note that you need to check if the return value is -1 before casting to char. Otherwise you can't tell if there was an error or if the byte read was actually -1.